# Missing fields in $http response

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have an app that at some point issues an $http POST to a WEB API project as follows

```
 $http({
        method: update ? "PUT" : "POST",
        url: framewidth + "inspections",
        data: data,
    }).then(
        function (object) {
            toastr.success(Messages.success.dflt);
            console.log(object.data);
            rtrn.resolve(object);            
        },
        function (error) {
            toastr.error(Messages.Error(error.statusText));
            rtrn.reject(error);
        }
    );
```

It saves fine but after it returns `object.data` is missing some fields. I have traced the missing fields all the way from the depths of the database to the Fiddler layer and the missing fields are there up until the `success` function of `$http`

So I can actually see my missing fields being returned in fiddler but they seem to disappear somewhere between that and `console.log(object.data);` line above.

I am totally stumped. It seems it's disappearing in the layer that's outside my control.

Comment: Can you look at the network traffic in your browser dev tools instead of Fiddler to see the response and paste it here? Sometimes a trying a different tool might help...

Comment: I looked at the response in the chrome's network tab and I can see the fields. The response is long; I'd rather not post it here. Let me know if there is anything particular you want to look for. Thanks!

Comment: try putting a breakpoint in your success function and look at `object` there. One thing I've noticed about Chrome's dev tools is that if you console.log an object and then the object changes before expand it, you might get the changed version rather than what it was at the time of getting logged.

Comment: Where are missing fields stored in object.data field or only in returned object itself?

Comment: @MrOBrian you are correct. console.log is not always 100% reliable. Submit and answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in doing this. I guess I need to check my messages on here more often :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a breakpoint in your success function and look at object there. One thing I've noticed about Chrome's dev tools is that if you `console.log` an object and then the object changes before you expand it, you might get the changed version rather than what it was at the time of getting logged.